# express.js PUT method doesn't run properly

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a simple project for practicing node and express. My GET methods work with no problem but my PUT method doesn't run. I don't know why nor how to fix it.

I tried putting my PUTmethod before my GET methods but it doesn't change a thing.

```
  app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
res.send("Welcome to our website");
  });

  app.get("/animes", (req, res)=>{
res.send(dataFile.animes);
  });

  app.get("/animes/:id", (req, res)=>{
res.send(dataFile.animes[req.params.id]);
  });

  app.put("/update", (req, res)=>{
console.log("hello");
  });
```

On the browser it keeps showing  "Cannot GET /update"

Comment: Maybe on the frontend you are actually triggering a `GET` request? Can you show us the frontend call too ?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? By the way, keep in mind you don't call `res.send()` in your PUT callback. So request just hangs and most likely get closed by timeout.

Comment: I don't have a frontend. I just want to practice how the query and parms objects works and how to modify a json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform PUT and POST requests you would need a client supporting the method; if you try it in the browser, it will perform a GET by default, that's why the browser displays: "Cannot GET /update".

If you want to consume the PUT you would need a client like CURL https://curl.haxx.se/ or Postman https://www.getpostman.com/.

If you have CURL and the server is running in the port 3000 it would be:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:3000/update
```